# Laravel commands short options

Tags: php, laravel, command, laravel-artisan

I am making a custom Artisan command in Laravel and I would like to pass in options. However I am seeing that for example `make:controller` has option to make a resource controller with either passing in `-r` or `--resource`. My command is now defined like this:

```
protected $signature = 'make {name} {--flag=?}';
```

But when I do a `-h` for command help, I see only `--flag` as an option. I would like to give an option to also write a `-f` and pass in flag as well.

I tried like this

```
protected $signature = 'make {name} {-f=?} {--flag=?}';
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taken from the [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/artisan#defining-input-expectations):

> Option Shortcuts
>
> To assign a shortcut when defining an option, you may
> specify it before the option name and use a | delimiter to separate
> the shortcut from the full option name:

The following ought to work for your case:

```
protected $signature = 'make {name} {--f|flag=}';
```

Comment: The question mark is unnecessary, as the options are already marked as optional.